# Странное поведение head

Tags: html, css

Помогите пожалуйста, верстал страничку наткнулся на странный отступ перед div.
Также все содержимое тега HEAD переместилось в BODY.
[image: Странный отступ]

Код странички

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include 'application/views/'.$content_view;?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        Шапка
    </div>
    <div  class="sidebar">
        <div class="menu">
            Меню
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <?php echo $content ?>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        Подвал
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Стили :

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Нужно для мобильного WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Нужно для Firefox */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #E1E1E1;
    font-size: 1.15em;
}

.header{
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 1.75em;
}

.content{
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 800px;
    margin: 0 0 0 30%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.sidebar{
    position: absolute;
    width: 14.55%;
    left: 14%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer{
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.sidebar, .content{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 1%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
.footer, .header{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    color: #D9D9D9;
    padding: 5px 0% 5px 2%;
}
.header:hover{
    color: white;
}
```

**Что не так с страничкой?????**

Comment: Не уверен, что поможет, но я бы попробовал <?php include 'application/views/'.$content_view;?> переместить на 10 строчку (сразу после <body>)

Comment: Как я уже выяснил от вставок php это не зависит.

Comment: Если дело не в <?php include 'application/views/'.$content_view;?> - то проблема может быть в кеше (попробуйте очистить кеш страницы)... попробовал ваш код у себя запустить - без вставок php всё работает гладко

Comment: И рекомендую добавить <meta lang="ru">

Comment: Без вставок php работает также есть отступ

Comment: При вставке вашего кода в ответ отступа нет. На [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Giryayev/pen/yVxyjj) тоже норм

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня такая байда была из за UTF-8 кодировки, он добавлял какой-то лишний символ в начало страницы. Попробуй в UTF-8 без БОМ перекодировать, в notepad++ это проще всего.

Comment: Ничего не поменялось(((

Comment: Проблема обнаружилась в двух кодировках UTF-8 w/o BOM UTF-8-BOM. Правильно было поставить кодировку UTF-8. И символы сами уходят